некорректно выводятся элементы таблицы БД через Tkinter
Приложение, созданное на Tkinter, представляет из себя таблицу БД, должно показывать данные типов text и integer, но выдает набор некорректных символов после того как принимает и сохраняет таблицу
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3

# Cоздание главного окна
class Main(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.init_main()
        self.db = db
        self.view_records()

    # Функция-конструктор главного окна 
    def init_main(self):
        # Создание области функций-инструментов добавления окон
        toolbar = tk.Frame(bg='#d7d7d7', bd=2)
        toolbar.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)

        #  Создание графической визуализации функции-инструмента поиска месяца
        self.add_img = tk.PhotoImage(file='C:/Users/Maxim/Documents/Python/UpdDB/2891642.png')
        btn_add = tk.Button(toolbar, bg='#d7d7d7', bd=0, image=self.add_img, command=self.open_dialog)
        btn_add.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        self.create_boxplot = tk.PhotoImage(file='C:/Users/Maxim/Documents/Python/UpdDB/3281111.png')
        btn_add = tk.Button(toolbar, bg='#d7d7d7', bd=0, image=self.create_boxplot, command=self.create)
        btn_add.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        #  Создание графической визуализации функции-инструмента редактирования месяца
        self.edit_img = tk.PhotoImage(file='C:/Users/Maxim/Documents/Python/UpdDB/1827951.png')
        btn_edit = tk.Button(toolbar, bg='#d7d7d7', bd=0, image=self.edit_img, command=self.open_edit)
        btn_edit.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        #  Создание графической визуализации функции-инструмента удаления месяца
        self.del_img = tk.PhotoImage(file='C:/Users/Maxim/Documents/Python/UpdDB/3221803.png')
        btn_del = tk.Button(toolbar, bg='#d7d7d7', bd=0, image=self.del_img, command=self.delete_records)
        btn_del.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        #  Создание графической визуализации функции-инструмента поиска месяца
        self.search_img = tk.PhotoImage(file='C:/Users/Maxim/Documents/Python/UpdDB/711319.png')
        btn_search = tk.Button(toolbar, bg='#d7d7d7', bd=0, image=self.search_img, command=self.open_search)
        btn_search.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

          #  Создание графической визуализации функции-инструмента обновления месяца
        self.refresh_img = tk.PhotoImage(file='C:/Users/Maxim/Documents/Python/UpdDB/64056.png')
        btn_refresh = tk.Button(toolbar, bg='#d7d7d7', bd=0, image=self.refresh_img, command=self.view_records)
        btn_refresh.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        # Создание таблицы
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=('id', 'month', 'revenue', 'income', 'prod_costs', 'indirect_costs', 'loan_percents', 'inc_tax', 'depreciation', 'path'), height=45, show='headings')

        # Добавление параметров столбцов
        self.tree.column('id', width=45, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column('month', width=150, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column('revenue', width=300, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column('income', width=150, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column('prod_costs', width=150, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column('indirect_costs', width=150, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column('loan_percents', width=150, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column('inc_tax', width=150, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column('depreciation', width=150, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column('path', width=150, anchor=tk.CENTER)

        self.tree.heading('id', text='id')
        self.tree.heading('month', text='Дата')
        self.tree.heading('revenue', text='Выручка')
        self.tree.heading('income', text='Чистая прибыль')
        self.tree.heading('prod_costs', text='Производственные расходы')
        self.tree.heading('indirect_costs', text='Косвенные расходы')
        self.tree.heading('loan_percents', text='Проценты по кредиту')
        self.tree.heading('inc_tax', text='Налог на прибыль')
        self.tree.heading('depreciation', text='Амортизация')
        self.tree.heading('path', text='Файл')
        self.tree.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        scroll = tk.Scrollbar(root, command=self.tree.yview)
        scroll.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.Y)
        self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)


    # Функция-инструмент записи
    def records(self, month, revenue, income, prod_costs, indirect_costs, loan_percents, inc_tax, depreciation, path):
        self.db.insert_data(month, revenue, income, prod_costs, indirect_costs, loan_percents, inc_tax, depreciation, path)
        self.view_records()

    # Функция-инструмент редактирования
    def edit_record(self, month, revenue, income, prod_costs, indirect_costs, loan_percents, inc_tax, depreciation, path):
        ind = self.tree.set(self.tree.selection()[0], '#1')
        self.db.cur.execute('''
        UPDATE econometrics SET month = ?, revenue = ?, income = ?, prod_costs = ?, indirect_costs = ?, loan_percents = ?, inc_tax = ?, depreciation = ?, path =?
        WHERE id = ? ''', (month, revenue, income, prod_costs, indirect_costs, loan_percents, inc_tax, depreciation, path, ind), )
        self.db.conn.commit()
        self.view_records()

    # Функция-инструмент удаления выделенной строки в таблице
    def delete_records(self):
        for i in self.tree.selection():
            id = self.tree.set(i, '#1')
            self.db.cur.execute('''
            DELETE FROM econometrics
            WHERE id = ?
        ''', (id, ))
        self.db.conn.commit()
        self.view_records()

    # Функция-инструмент поиска
    def search_records(self, month):
        [self.tree.delete(i)  for i in self.tree.get_children()] 
        self.db.cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM econometrics WHERE month LIKE ?""", 
                            ('%' + month + '%',))
        [self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=i)  for i in self.db.cur.fetchall()]


    def create(self):
        Creating_boxplot(root)

    # Вызов придаточного окна
    def open_dialog(self):
        Additional(root)

    # Вызов окна редактирования
    def open_edit(self):
        Update()

    def open_search(self):
        Search(root)


    def view_records(self):
        self.db.cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM econometrics""")
        [self.tree.delete(i)  for i in self.tree.get_children()]
        [self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=i)  for i in self.db.cur.fetchall()]


    def boxplotting(self, month):
        month = ('%' + month + '%')
        path = db.cur.execute("""SELECT path FROM econometrics WHERE month LIKE ?""", (month, ))
        df = pd.read_excel(path)
        fig = Figure(figsize=(20, 10), dpi=1000)
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111) 

        labels = df.columns.tolist()
        red_circle = dict(markerfacecolor='mediumseagreen', marker= 'o')
        mean_shape = dict(markerfacecolor='green', marker= '+')
        ax.set_ylabel('Значения (руб.)')

        bplot = ax.boxplot(df,
                           patch_artist=True,
                           vert=True,
                           flierprops=red_circle,
                           showmeans=True,
                           meanprops=mean_shape,
                           tick_labels=labels,
                           notch=True)
        
        bplot.set_facecolor('black')
        for boxes in zip(bplot['boxes']):
            boxes.set_facecolor('turquoise')

        canvas1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = app)
        canvas1.draw()
        canvas1.get_tk_widget().pack(side='top', fill=None, expand=0)
        app.after(200, None) 


# Создание придаточного окна
class Additional(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.init_additional()
        self.view = app

    # Функция-конструктор придаточного окна
    def init_additional(self):
        self.title('Добавление информации по месяцу')
        self.geometry('450x200')
        # Запрет на изменение размеров окна
        self.resizable(False, False)
        # Установка перехвата всех событий приложения
        self.grab_set()
        # Установка захвата фокуса
        self.focus_set()

        # Создание графической визуализации таблицы
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Выберите файл", filetype=(("Excel", "*.xlsx"), ("Excel", "*.xls"), ("Excel", "*.csv")))
        path = filename 
        df = pd.read_excel(path)
        df = df.assign(Чистая_прибыль = df['Выручка'] - (df['Производственные_расходы']+ df['Косвенные_расходы']+ df['Налог_на_прибыль'] + df['Проценты_по_кредитам'] + df['Амортизация']))
        label_month = tk.Label(self, text='Месяц')
        label_month.place(x=50, y=50)

        self.entry_month = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_month.place(x=200, y=50)
        self.entry_revenue = df['Выручка'].sum()
        self.entry_income = df['Чистая_прибыль'].sum()
        self.entry_prod_costs = df['Производственные_расходы'].sum()
        self.entry_indirect_costs = df['Косвенные_расходы'].sum()
        self.entry_loan_percents = df['Проценты_по_кредитам'].sum()
        self.entry_inc_tax = df['Налог_на_прибыль'].sum()
        self.entry_depreciation = df['Амортизация'].sum()
        self.entry_path = path

        self.btn_ok = tk.Button(self, text='Добавить')
        self.btn_ok.bind('<Button-1>', lambda ev: self.view.records(self.entry_month.get(),
                                                                    self.entry_revenue,
                                                                    self.entry_income, 
                                                                    self.entry_indirect_costs,
                                                                    self.entry_prod_costs,
                                                                    self.entry_loan_percents,
                                                                    self.entry_inc_tax,
                                                                    self.entry_depreciation,
                                                                    self.entry_path))
        self.btn_ok.place(x=300, y=160)             

        btn_cancel = tk.Button(self, text='Закрыть', command=self.destroy)
        btn_cancel.place(x=220, y=160)  


class Update(Additional):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.db = db
        self.init_edit()
        self.load_data()

    def init_edit(self):
        self.title('Изменение текущей информации')
        # Удаление функции-инструмента добавления
        self.btn_ok.destroy()
        # Добавление функции-инструмента редактирования
        self.btn_ok = tk.Button(self, text='Редактировать')
        self.btn_ok.bind('<Button-1>', 
                         lambda ev: self.view.edit_record(
                            self.entry_month.get(),
                            self.entry_revenue,
                            self.entry_income, 
                            self.entry_prod_costs,
                            self.entry_indirect_costs,
                            self.entry_loan_percents,
                            self.entry_inc_tax,
                            self.entry_depreciation,
                            self.entry_path))
        self.btn_ok.bind('<Button-1>', lambda ev: self.destroy(), add='+')
        self.btn_ok.place(x=300, y=160)   

    #  Функция-инструмент заполнения старыми данными
    def load_data(self):
        self.db.cur.execute('''SELECT * FROM econometrics WHERE id = ? ''',
                        self.view.tree.set(self.view.tree.selection()[0], '#1'))
        row = self.db.cur.fetchone()
        self.entry_month.insert(0, row[1])
        self.entry_revenue.insert(0, row[2])
        self.entry_income.insert(0, row[3])
        self.entry_prod_costs.insert(0, row[4])
        self.entry_indirect_costs.insert(0, row[5])
        self.entry_loan_percents.insert(0, row[6])
        self.entry_inc_tax.insert(0, row[7])
        self.entry_depreciation.insert(0, row[8])
        self.entry_path.insert(0, row[9])

#  Создание поискового окна
class Search(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.init_search()
        self.view = app

    # Функция-конструктор окна поиска
    def init_search(self):
        self.title('Поиск по дате')
        self.geometry('300x100')
        # Запрет на изменение размеров окна
        self.resizable(False, False)
        #  Установка перехвата всех событий приложения
        self.grab_set()
        # Установка захвата фокуса
        self.focus_set()

        # Создание графической визуализации окна поиска
        label_month = tk.Label(self, text='Дата')
        label_month.place(x=50, y=30)
        label_month.pack(anchor='nw', padx=6, pady=6)
    
        self.entry_month = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_month.place(x=150, y=30)
        self.entry_month.pack(anchor='nw', padx=6, pady=6)

        self.btn_ok = tk.Button(self, text='Найти')
        self.btn_ok.bind('<Button-1>', lambda ev: self.view.search_records(self.entry_month.get()))
        self.btn_ok.bind('<Button-1>', lambda ev: self.destroy(), add='+')
        self.btn_ok.place(x=230, y=70)             

        btn_cancel = tk.Button(self, text='Закрыть', command=self.destroy)
        btn_cancel.place(x=160, y=70)  


class Creating_boxplot(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.db = db
        self.init_creating()
        self.view = app

    def init_creating(self):
        self.title('Создание графика')
        self.geometry('300x100')    
        # Запрет на изменение размеров окна
        self.resizable(False, False)
        #  Установка перехвата всех событий приложения
        self.grab_set()
        # Установка захвата фокуса
        self.focus_set()

        label_month = tk.Label(self, text='Дата')
        label_month.place(x=50, y=30)
        label_month.pack(anchor='nw', padx=6, pady=6)
    
        self.entry_month = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_month.place(x=150, y=30)
        self.entry_month.pack(anchor='nw', padx=6, pady=6)
        
        self.btn_ok = tk.Button(self, text='Создать')
        self.btn_ok.bind('<Button-1>', lambda ev: self.view.boxplotting(self.entry_month.get()))
        self.btn_ok.place(x=230, y=70) 

        btn_cancel = tk.Button(self, text='Закрыть', command=self.destroy)
        btn_cancel.place(x=160, y=70) 
       
        



#  Создание БД
class Db():
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect('info.db')
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()
        self.cur.execute ('''
                CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS econometrics (
                        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                        month TEXT,
                        revenue INTEGER,
                        income INTEGER,
                        prod_costs INTEGER,
                        indirect_costs INTEGER,
                        loan_percents INTEGER,
                        inc_tax INTEGER,
                        depreciation INTEGER,
                        path TEXT  
                )''')
        
    # Функция-инструмент добавления в БД
    def insert_data(self, month, revenue, income, prod_costs, indirect_costs, loan_percents, inc_tax, depreciation, path):
        self.cur.execute('''
        INSERT INTO econometrics (month, revenue, income, prod_costs, indirect_costs, loan_percents, inc_tax, depreciation, path)
                         VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)''', (month, revenue, income, prod_costs, indirect_costs, loan_percents, inc_tax, depreciation, path))
        self.conn.commit()



# Создание окна и вызов класса Main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    db = Db()
    app = Main(root)
    app.pack()
    root.title('Таблица для эконометрики')
    root.geometry('1000x600')
    # Запрет на изменение размеров окна
    root.resizable(False, False)
    root.mainloop()

